# Can't build in Xcode 4.5 because of "Multiple methods named" error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm having problems with building my project in Xcode 4.5. Xcode gives me this error "Multiple methods named 'item' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes". Can someone tell me what the problem is? how to resolve multiple methods names error?

Comment: Please find the relevant code snippet (which Xcode marks) for 'items'

Answer (score 1):

You probably have different classes implementing the method `item` but returning a different type of result. If you then try to invoke `item` on an `id` typed pointer, there's no way to know what the result type is supposed to be.

That's what XCode is lamenting about.

How to solve it depends a lot on what are you really are trying to do. Probably using different names for the methods is the best solution.

Comment: It's working on x-code 4.4 then when I integrated on x-code 4.5 the error appeared.

Comment: Either 4.5 is catching problems that 4.4 did not catch or the problem is elsewhere, but it's hard to say if you do not post your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method namespace collision occur, as in Analog File's post - invoking on an id pointer, you can resolve the "Multiple methods named.." error by casting the pointer to an acceptable class type.

So, presuming your original (error provoking) call was something like:

```
id myPointer = /* ... */;
[myPointer item];
```

You can command+click on "item" which will display the multiple classes XCode can send that message to.  Cast to one of those classes so XCode knows which one to use, to something like:

```
[(UIActivityItemProvider*)myPointer item];
```